# Plain old query string with jquery-address

Tags: javascript, jquery, deep-linking, jquery-address

i'm implementing deep linking for my website.

I wonder, why jquery-address is unable just to set a query string, like this:

```
www.mywebsite.com?search=keyword
```

When i using

```
$.address.parameter("search", "keyword")
```

jquery-address sets follwing url:

```
www.mywebsite.com?search#/?keyword
```

Why, it doing so ?

I just need the plain old query string, like in my first example.

Help, please !

Comment: Out of interest why are you using jquery for something like this?  Why not just set window.location in javascript which is presumably what jquery is doing anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Those addresses use the hash, which is because they're meant for the client.  If you want to manipulate the query string, you can use the [query plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/query-object).  E.g.:

```
window.location.search = $.query.set('search', 'keyword');
```

EDIT:

If you wanted to make multiple changes, you could do, e.g.:

```
var newQuery = $.query.set('search', 'keyword');
// ...
newQuery = newQuery.set('another', 'value');
window.location.search = newQuery;
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be working with simple case of setting.

But i have troubles with setting values, separated with comma. This code: window.location.search = $.query.set('search', 'keyword1, keyword2') produces the URL like this: www.mywebsite.com?search=keyword1%2C%2Bkeyword2. The %2C code is ok, because it is comma, but the %2B is strange, because it is "+" sign. So, it sets ?search=keyword1,+keyword2 instead of ?search=keyword, keyword2

Comment: `+` is used for space in [application/x-www-form-urlencoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding#The_application.2Fx-www-form-urlencoded_type).  However, I don't know if that URL is exactly correct.

Comment: Hmm. Setting window.location forces redirection to modified URL and reloading the page. Unfortunately, this way is not suitable for me ...

Comment: @Anton, you can not change the query string without forcing a load.  That is why jquery-address (and other code) uses the hash (the part after the `#`).  However, you can make multiple changes to the query string with a single load.  I added an example of that.

Comment: Thanks. I've switched to use hash-values. Everything is working now.